# nuttx hex too large

Tags: bootloader, teensy

I have a teensy 4.1, and I am trying to install NUTTX the Real Time Operating System ( RTOS ). Teensy is a supported platform.
I am trying install nuttx compiled from source, and upload it using the [teensy loader program](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/loader_linux.html). my current issue is that the hex file is too large. the file size is 229Kb, which shouldn't be an issue where the flash size for a teensy 4.1 is 8MB.

I have been following the steps on these websites:
this one where [Nuttx is installed on a teensy 3](https://acassis.wordpress.com/2016/04/16/running-nuttx-on-teensy-3-1/), and the documentation for [nuttx on their website](https://nuttx.apache.org/docs/latest/quickstart/compiling.html)

any tips or recommendations to install nuttx on a teensy 4.1 would be greatly appreciated.

[image: nutt.hex file too large]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I pressed the reset button and the teensy loader program reset, and reloaded the hex file. Now it lists as I would expect it to, using 1% of the flash space. and uploads without error. [image]